# Is it possible to use more than one software architecture pattern in a single software? If so, how would this work?

Tags: architectural-patterns

I already know of various software design patterns, and I am familiar with MVC.
However, now that I am learning about other patterns (repository, client-server, pipe, and layered), I got a bit confused about the implementation of these patterns.

Can there be a combination of patterns in a single software system? If so, how would this work?

Comment: see [Why is "Is it possible to:" a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: Have you used a website? Then you very likely have used a software system that uses *some form* of MV* (e.g. MVC, MVP, MVVM, HMVC) and that is also, simply by the very nature of how the web works, client-server.

Comment: Are they over-teaching "Patterns" in CompSci courses now? I feel the site has been flooded with questions about Pattern usage where the person posting the question clearly has very little experience actually using/understanding them.

Comment: "skyscraper" and "mud hut" are two distinct architectural styles. Is it possible to build a mud hut on top of my skyscraper? Sure, why not. Do I need to and/or is it a good idea? Well that's a completely different question.

Comment: @Graham: I mean, you're not wrong, but that's a biased observation. If they fully understood a pattern, they wouldn't be asking a question about the pattern itself. All you can really infer is that more people seem to want to learn about patterns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's focus on the architectural patterns you mentioned (*repository, client-server, pipe, layered*).

A client-server system consists of programs or components which run on the client, and others which run on the server. Each of these components can have a layer structure internally. One of these layer may be a repository layer (for example, for decoupling other parts of the program from the database access code).

Both the client components as well as the server components may contain a "business logic layer". And for certain kinds of business logic, it makes sense for this layer to be structured internally by pipes and filters. For example, a 3D rendering engine on the client side can be structured by using a rendering pipeline. A system which does heavily asynchronous batch processing on the server side (for example, for filling / updating a data ware house every night) can have a batch processing pipeline.

So in short, different architectural patterns appear at different levels of abstraction. And in any larger real-world system one will usually find several of those patterns.

Comment: The last paragraph was clear actually. The architecture patterns differ based on the level of abstraction.